# Create a CGContextRef for existing CGImageRef

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgimage

Suppose I have an existing CGImageRef. I would like to create a CGContextRef for that existing  image and draw something in it.

Considering that the CGImageRef has an underlying data array in memory, my guess is that it should be possible to create a new context using `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData` and pass as data array the underlying memory data from CGImageRef.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the data array from a CGImageRef (might not even be possible).

Please note that I prefer not to create a new context, draw the old image and then the new content.

Comment: Could you get the `CGDataProviderRef` from image, and then call `CGDataProviderCopyData()` on it?

Comment: Yes, I can. But wouldn't copy data first copy the entire image to a new location? I'm trying to avoid that. If it's not possible, then I will go with the copydata way.